# sharepoint list suddenly stops syncing

Tags: sharepoint-list, sync

So I got this list that several people are working in.. Everything in the morning works just fine, when I do a change in the list it updates on my colleges computer in a matter of seconds. But after a few hours it suddenly stops working and we have to restart the browser for it so start syncing again.

Someone have any ideés what can cause this?

Comment: Someone who can help?

Comment: I think a bit more information is needed for someone here to help troubleshoot.  Which version of SharePoint are you using?  Do multiple users have this problem or just one?  Do you get an error message?  Which browser is used when the problem occurs?  Can you find more detailed information in the developer pane of the browser?

Comment: I'm using O365, modern sharepoint, multiple people have this issue, no error message and everyone is using google chrome but we have tested other browsers too. I've been in contact with microsoft support but with no luck :(